# Another PHP Syntax Error

Tags: php, syntax-error

This is the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/idghosti/public_html/testground/mma/include/footer.php on line 9

This is the code:

```
<?php
    } else {
        error_reporting(0);

        if  (mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n"))

        //Message sent!
        //It the message that will be displayed when the user click the sumbit button
        //You can modify the text if you want
        echo nl2br("
        <div class=\"MsgSent\">
            <h1>Congratulations!!</h1>
            <p>Thank you <b>$name</b>, your message is sent!<br /> We will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>
        </div>
       ");

        else

        // Display error message if the message failed to send
        echo "
        <div class=\"MsgError\">
            <h1>Error!!</h1>
            <p>Sorry <b><?=$name;?></b>, your message failed to send. Try later!</p>
        </div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: is there anything else in the file above the first line?

Comment: Also, try to use {} for if/else and all block constructs.

Comment: thi is the coe before it 

<?php
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){
      $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>

Can you please paste the solution as i't just starting to learn php

Comment: If you add that code to the top of the code posted, the code is valid and you don't get a parse error

Comment: yes but in between those code is a form 

<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){ $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>

Then the Form

adn teh alst chunk of the PHP is inside of an include

Comment: I Don't know if it would help but when the page is not templated everything works like a charmed but when break them into includes it just doesn't work

Comment: Here is the sample fomr that I have downloaded and followed everything works perfectly when its not templated but once I break it apart it jsut doeen't work

http://web-kreation.com/index.php/articles/lightform-free-ajaxphp-contact-form/

Comment: Make the first PHP code an include. aka toppart.php and then the code you posted put it into a file called middlepart.php. put the includes where the PHP code would otherwise be.

Comment: Check out my answer, i updated it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code. I recommend looking at some tutorials for IF statements to understand how they work. Here is a good web site for you to do this.

[www.tizag.com](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/ifelse.php)

### **UPDATE to reflect comments:**

Take the PHP code block before the form and put it into **toppart.php**

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){ $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

------------------Your Form Code is here---------------------

Take this PHP code block after the form and put it into **middlepart.php**

```
<?php

} else {
    error_reporting(0);

    if  (mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n")) 

    //Message sent!
    //It the message that will be displayed when the user click the sumbit button
    //You can modify the text if you want
    echo nl2br("
    <div class=\"MsgSent\">
            <h1>Congratulations!!</h1>
            <p>Thank you <b>$name</b>, your message is sent!<br /> We will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>
    </div>
   ");


    else

    // Display error message if the message failed to send
    echo "
    <div class=\"MsgError\">
            <h1>Error!!</h1>
            <p>Sorry <b><?=$name;?></b>, your message failed to send. Try later!</p>
    </div>";


} 


?>
```

Your new code will look like the following:

```
include 'toppart.php';

/* Your Form Code Here */

include 'middlepart.php';
```

Unfortunately people on this web site will give you a hard time for posting questions such as these so it is good to do research before coming here for help. PHP coding can be very frustrating when you cannot figure out a problem. I am here to help. If you have any more questions feel free to leave a comment.

Best of Luck!! Learning PHP can be very rewarding.

Answer (score 7):

PHP blocks cannot span files. It looks like that is what you are trying to do.

Also if you are breaking out of blocks to output HTML directly, I find it more readable to use the [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Answer (score 1):

There's an unexpected '}', you're missing an `if(var){` on top.

Comment: Can you please paste the full code so I might see the difference since im just startng to learn PHP